# How to get Attribute-values out of XML-Style String

Tags: xml, string, svg, attributes

I have a Question About string-methods or something to work with string.

For my Website, I get some svg-ELements, that are stored in a database string-field.
When loading the Website, These Elements are loaded and decorated with some additional svg-Attributes:
(here Content is an iList of some recordsets, loaded in an Action)

```
var symbolstring="";
for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    var symbol = content[i];
    symbolstring += "<g class='preview variant' id='" + symbol.Id.toString()
        + "' pointer-events='fill' transform='translate("
        + positionX.toString() + ","
        + positionY.toString() + ")' >"
        + symbol.SvgString
        + "</g>";
}
$('#svgDrawing').html(symbolstring);
```

Such a svg-String (symbol.svgString) Looks something like this:

```
<desc>
<Insert x='110' y='131'/>
<Pins>
    <Pin Id='1' x='110' y='131' direction='left' />
    <Pin Id='2' x='110' y='131' direction='right' />
</Pins>
<Properties>
    <Property Id='20010' x='187' y='110' angle='0' text-anchor='middle'></Property>
</Properties>
</desc>
<rect x="100" y="150" width="21" height="21" fill="none" />
<line x1="110" y1="150" x2="110" y2="131" fill="none" />
<text id='BMK' xml:space="preserve" y="187" x="110" text-anchor="middle" fill="#000000" stroke-width="0" font-size="16px" font-family="Sans-serif">#{BMK}</text>
```

My Goal is to calculate the Transformation-x and -y Position, depending on the Insert Attribute:

```
<Insert x='110' y='131'/>
```

Is there an easy way to read the x and y value out of the string?

Comment: Have you tried using regex capture groups?

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName("Insert")[0].getAttribute("x") etc

Comment: does document work, if this is a string in a variable?
This string isn't added to the document yet. It should after calculationg the insert Position.

Comment: capturegroups could get me the Insert-string and then I could split the string and read the second and the third value, here extract the value between the quotionmarks.
Seems also not very comfortable, or how would you use the regex capture Groups?